# Why is it "Do a Barrel Roll" and not "Does a Barrel Roll"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Google search throws you a nice effect when you try searching "Do a Barrel Roll."

Should not it be "Does a Barrel Roll," assuming it's one Barrel (or barrel), or at least "Do a Barrels Roll"? (I assume it should be a question: "Does a barrel roll?" or "Do a barrels roll?")

EDIT: The problem is that I didn't know that "Do a barrel roll" wasn't a question. (Yes, it hadn't a question mark, but I felt that there was an historic reason not to add it.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Does a barrel roll?

is a question asking whether a [*barrel*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/barrel_1?q=barrel) rolls.

> Do a barrel roll!

is an instruction ordering the pilot to perform a [*barrel roll*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/barrel-roll?q=barrel%20roll).

Comment: That's it. I didn't know it isn't a question

Comment: Do barrels roll?  Yes.  Does a barrel roll?  Only when the barrel is on its side.  Do a barrel roll?  OK, but I'm not even in a plane or playing Star Fox!

Comment: Why did the barrel cross the road? No, wait, mine didn't turn out funny :|

Comment: "I can does a barrel roll?" if the pilot is a lolcat.

Answer (score 8):

This comes from the video game [Star Fox 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Fox_64).

In it, you fly around in a ship shooting stuff, and getting shot at by stuff.  If you "do a [barrel roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_roll)" (rotate your ship quickly along its axis of flight ie. rotate its [roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes)), you are momentarily invincible.

Because of this, [one of the other characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppy#Peppy_Hare) *constantly* contacts you over the radio to tell you to **"DO A BARREL ROLL!"**  It became increasingly annoying and inappropriate, because by the end of the game *I know when to do a friggin' barrel roll already!*

Because it was repeated so often, the phrase became engrained in our minds.  And because the game was so popular, the phrase soon became an [Internet meme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_meme)

Comment: Made quite a bit worse by the fact that in Star Fox you're actually performing an [aileron roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aileron_roll), not a [barrel roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_roll). I suspect English.SE appreciates the distinction.

Comment: @Christopher: +1, I never knew that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

"[Barrel roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_roll)" is a noun (it's a maneuver that airplanes can do). "Do a barrel roll" is an imperative phrase where "barrel roll" is the direct object.

Answer (score 3):

I take the verb to be an imperative, so *Do a Barrel Roll* seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because people would more likely search for *"How can I do a barrel roll?"* or *"How to do a barrel roll?"*.

Answer (score 2):

"Barrel Roll" is a noun phrase.

"Do" is the imperative form of the verb.

"Do a (Barrel Roll)" is the same as "Do a (dance)"